# How can I make a combined plot of a rotated ellipse and the the same ellipse unrotated?

Tags: plotting, geometry

I want to make two plots, `p1` and `p2`, of the same ellipse. In `p1` the ellipse is rotated 30 degree and `p2` in ellipse not rotated.

```
p1 = 
  GeometricTransformation[
    ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2/49 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -5, 5}, 
      PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1],
    RotationTransform[30 Degree]];

p2 = 
  ContourPlot[x^2+y^2/49 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -50, 50}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 1];

Show[p1, p2, PlotRange->Automatic]
```

But I get the following message:

> Could not combine the graphics objects in

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GeometricTransform` doesn't work on your `Graphics`. The documentation says that it works on *geometric objects*. It easier if you simply transform your equation

```
rot = Thread[{x, y} -> RotationMatrix[-Pi/180*30].{x, y}]
eq1 = x^2 + y^2/49 == 1
eq2 = eq1 /. rot

ContourPlot[Evaluate[{eq1, eq2}], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you like to use `GeometricTransform`, then you need to apply it to the graphics-primitives and not the whole graphics. Therefore, you need to replace the line primitives inside your plot:

```
f = GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[30 Degree]] &;
ContourPlot[Evaluate[eq1], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}] /. l_Line :> f[l]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks for your reply.your method use `RotationMatrix`,I am not sure if any method use `RotationTransform`

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica's geometric region capabilities makes what you want to do very simple.

```
p2 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2/49 == 1, {x, y}];
p1 = TransformedRegion[p2, RotationTransform[30 °]];
Show[Region[p1, BaseStyle -> Red], Region[p2, BaseStyle -> Blue], Frame -> True]
```

[image: ellipses]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`Circle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle) primitives instead of [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot)?

```
Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0,0}, {1,7}], Blue, Rotate[Circle[{0,0},{1,7}], 30 Degree]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to make it complicated (just a personal opinion based on the use of minimal MMA functions, although I acknowledge and value the other answers). Just use the equation of the rotated ellipse in the plane.

However a question rises: 30 degrees rotated in what direction?

Here, the rotation is from y-axis to x-axis (positive, clockwise):

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[((x Cos[#] - y Sin[#])^2 + (y Cos[#] + x Sin[#])^2/49 == 1) & /@ 
{0, \[Pi]/6}], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]